# Right options to draw a matrix of rectangles

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

Considering the following TeX code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (mat) at (7,-4) [matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&,
    nodes={draw,rectangle}]
    {
      \node {B}; \& \node {B}; \& \node {B}; \& \node {B}; \\
      \node {0}; \& \node {1}; \& \node {B}; \& \node {B}; \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What are the right options to choose so that all the horizontal and vertical lines have the same thickness?

Answer (score 3):

You can try with the minimum width and height option :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (mat) at (7,-4) [matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&,
    nodes={draw,rectangle, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm}]
    {
      B \& B \& B \& B \\
      0 \& 1 \& B \& B \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With a `matrix of nodes` there's no need for `\node` inside matrix elements, just their contents: `B \& B \& B ...` is enough. And for equal lines with, it's better to use `col sep=-\pgflinewidth`, without it boxes are one beside the other and lines between rows and columns look wider.